# Mobile app and cloud

Tags: mobile, cloud

I need to develop an mobile app that is able to:
1) Allow users create profiles with a login system;
2) An area that allow users to search profiles near them by geo position.
Is not an production app, I just need to learn how the things work..
1) To developer a app thus as explained, I need a web service.
But, what is the complete infrastructure needed to deploy this app?

I had read that the amazon delivery one solution called S3...this is all that I need to know as example to study?

What are all the requirements to study this kind of solution by complete???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 is a storage solution, not really what you are looking for I think. Look at Google's Cloud Endpoints. Simple REST service with lots of tutorials. https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-endpoints/